# How to stop the spring boot through code after successful execution

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jenkins

I have a rest service and which will start once Its started I will invoke few endpoint URL and manually kill the running program in eclipse. I just implemented the same on Jenkins and I want to run them in Jenkins. But the problem is the port is active and still running and it's not able to let the jenkins to perform post build action. So I just want to kill the spring boot once all the rest calls are invoked and let the jenkins to execute the post build activity.

Can someone help me to achieve this? I just need some idea not working code.

Comment: have a look on the following link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown

Comment: Just now I gone through that link. It really helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Samim for your input. The below lines works as expected.

```
   ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestClass.class).run();
   ctx.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Layne - But I cant accept my answer for next two days. I'm getting such notifications.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there was a time limit on it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot privodes an actuator module, if you active the module with endpoints shutdown enabled(add endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true to your application.properties/application.yml file).
You can call /shutdown url to shutdown your spring boot application, after you finished your rest urls.

Endpoints:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready